# Column already exists when creating database

Tags: sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to save a form using Xamarin and SQLite.

I'm trying to create the local db like this:

```
    SQLiteConnection db;

    public MoodDatabaseController()
    {
        db = DependencyService.Get<ISQLite>().GetConnection();
        db.CreateTable<MoodEntry>();
    }
```

MoodEntry

```
public class MoodEntry
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int MoodEntryID { get; set; }

    [Indexed]
    public DateTime EntryDate { get; set; }
    ...
```

GetConnection():

```
    public SQLite_Android() { }
    public SQLite.SQLiteConnection GetConnection()
    {
        var sqliteFileName = "myMood.db3";
        string documentsPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment
                                    .SpecialFolder.Personal);
        var path = Path.Combine(documentsPath, sqliteFileName);
        var conn = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(path);

        return conn;
    }
```

Error: 
"SQLite.SQLiteException: duplicate column name: MoodEntryID"

How can it already exists if I only defined it once?

EDIT:

https://github.com/lasseedsvik/myMood

EDIT 2:

I also added an empty ctor to avoid that error

Comment: Are you sure that there is not an existing DB from a prior app session? i.e. Check of the table exists before executing CreateTable

Comment: Tried clean solution, restarts and all. Also CreateTable method says "Creates a table if not exists on the database" as tooltip, so I guess it would skip it if it already exists.

Comment: Android project?

Comment: Yes, got iOS project too but running Android as startup. I'll add a github incase ppl wanna look more closely.

Comment: Under the global setting for `Projects` / `Android`, is "Preserve data/cache between application deploys" enabled?

Comment: I unchecked that, cleaned solution, restarted comp, and I still get same error.

Comment: Manually delete the app from the device/emulator (via Setting / Apps) or via cmd-line:`adb uninstall your.app.packagename`, do you still get the same error?

Comment: Did you put a breakpoint on this line to see how many times it has been called on the first time you run the app?

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza it errors on first hit

Comment: @SushiHangover still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I noticed I couldnt update Xamarin packages and getting weird output, I redid the whole solution from scratch and updated Xamarin packages and that solved it for me.